# rails test, getting Failure:..Expected 0 to be >= 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages). In section *3.4.1 Testing Titles (Red)* the author writes a minitest test using assert_select viz.

```
test "should get home" do
  get static_pages_home_url
  assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end
```

Then he expects the following output on running rails test:

```
1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

However, when I run the exact same test on my local system I get this failure message instead:

```
# Running:

FF

Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home [/Users/gurpreet/environment/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:7]:
<Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
<SampleApp>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Someone please explain why am I not getting the intended rails test result. Please note that the actual section in the tutorial has 3 tests and 6 assertions but I have just posted the relevant details for readability, using single test and single assertion inside it.

Here is full Controller Test Class:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

As I mentioned earlier it contains extra tests of similar nature. I only posted a snippet of this class earlier.

The View part of controller deliberately omit the `<title>` tag to make the test to fail. For example in case of home.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sample App</h1>
    <p>
      This is the home page for the
      <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
      sample application
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you upload the class you're testing against?

Comment: Hartl is teaching you Test Driven Development, where you write a test that you expect to fail, and then write code to make it pass. When tests fail, you get a synopsis why they failed, and then you get a summary line counting how many tests passed and failed. Now add the `<title>` tag and pass the test!

Comment: @Phlip You are right, I also expect the tests to fail because there is no `<title>` tag. The problem is that in the tutorial there is a nice summary line at the end of test showing the count of failed tests, but in my case there is no summary line and tests seem to stop at first failure.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you're using a default reporter that's built into Minitest. 
I saw a similar Minitest summary with minitest-reporters gem: 
https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters

Comment: Thanks @wondersz1, but I cannot confirm if it works yet as I have moved away from Ruby on Rails at the moment.